SAS Transpose and summarise data
I have a dataset that looks like this:
   Account Number  6m      7m      8m      9m      10m     11m     6m_Metric    7m_metric   8m_metric   9m_metric   10m_metric      11m_metric
    1               Better  X < 10  X < 10  Better  X < 30  X < 30    0.6       0.6         0.9         1.2         0.1             5.0
    2               X < 10  X < 20  X < 30  X < 20  X < 20  X < 20    0.4       0.4         3.4         3.7         4.4             0.3
    3               Better  Better  Better  Better  X < 10  X < 20    1.5       1.5         1.5         0.3         1.5             1.8
    4               X < 10  Better  Same    Same    Same    Same      3.4       3.4         1.8         5.0         5.2             6.8
    5               Same    Better  Same    Same    Same    Same      0.1       0.1         5.0         5.3         5.0             1.8
    6               Same    Same    Same    Better  Better  Better    4.4       4.4         0.3         0.3         5.2             7.4
    7               Same    X < 10  X < 10  X < 10  X < 10  Better    5.0       5.0         1.3         2.1         2.2             0.3
    8               Better  Better  Better  Better  Better  Better    7.8       7.8         5.0         1.5         1.9             7.4
    9               X < 10  X < 10  X < 10  X < 20  X < 30  Better    9.1       9.1         9.4         5.5         5.6             4.6
    10              X < 20  X < 30  X < 30  X < 30  X < 30  X < 30    0.3       0.3         1.5         1.8         2.2             1.5

Where each cell tells me what's happened 6-11 months later for each account number as well as the metric value for each month for each account number. I want to be able to show any trends here so I'd like to be able to have number of accounts with "Better" etc for each month but also the average metric amount for this month. So I think it should look something like:
Result  6m  7m  8m  9m  10m 11m Avg_met_6m Avg_met_7m       Avg_met_8m  Avg_met_9m  Avg_met_10m  Avg_met_11m
X < 10  3   3   3   2   3   0       4.3         4.3         3.9             2.9         3.9         2.2
X < 20  1   1   0   1   1   2       0.3         0.3         3.4             0           4.4         0.3
X < 30  0   1   2   1   2   1       0           0           1.5             2.8         2.2         3.3
Same    3   1   3   2   2   2       3.2         3.2         0.3             3.5         5.1         4.3
Better  1   4   2   4   2   4       3.3         3.3         3.3             0.9         2.2         7.4

I've just tried to get an example to illustrate what I'm trying to do, apologies if there are any typos.
data have;
    infile datalines dlm='|';
    input "Account Number"n "6m"n$ "7m"n$ "8m"n$ "9m"n$ "10m"n$ "11m"n$ "6m_Metric"n "7m_Metric"n "8m_Metric"n "9m_Metric"n "10m_Metric"n "11m_Metric"n;
    datalines;
1|Better|X < 10|X < 10|Better|X < 30|X < 30|0.6|0.6|0.9|1.2|0.1|5.0
2|X < 10|X < 20|X < 30|X < 20|X < 20|X < 20|0.4|0.4|3.4|3.7|4.4|0.3
3|Better|Better|Better|Better|X < 10|X < 20|1.5|1.5|1.5|0.3|1.5|1.8
4|X < 10|Better|Same|Same|Same|Same|3.4|3.4|1.8|5.0|5.2|6.8
5|Same|Better|Same|Same|Same|Same|0.1|0.1|5.0|5.3|5.0|1.8
6|Same|Same|Same|Better|Better|Better|4.4|4.4|0.3|0.3|5.2|7.4
7|Same|X < 10|X < 10|X < 10|X < 10|Better|5.0|5.0|1.3|2.1|2.2|0.3
8|Better|Better|Better|Better|Better|Better|7.8|7.8|5.0|1.5|1.9|7.4
9| X < 10|X < 10|X < 10|X < 20|X < 30|Better|9.1|9.1|9.4|5.5|5.6|4.6
10| X < 20|X < 30|X < 30|X < 30|X < 30|X < 30|0.3|0.3|1.5|1.8|2.2|1.5
;
run;


I took the following approach:

Some transposing to get the data into a workable format
PROC TABULATE to calculate the results and also output the results to a data set
More transposing to get these results into the desired format

(I would recommend keeping the data in the intermediate format as it may be easier to work with.)
* Transpose the character variables;
proc transpose data=have out=char_t (rename = col1 = Result) name = time;
    by 'account number'n;
    var _character_;
run;

* Transpose the numeric variables;
proc transpose data=have out=num_t (where = (time ne 'Account Number') rename = col1 = Metric) name = time ;
    by 'account number'n;
    var _numeric_;
run;

* Recode the time variable to match char_t;
data num_t (rename = t = time drop = time);
    length t $ 3;
    set num_t;
    t = prxchange('s/\_Metric\s*$//', -1, time);
run;

* Merge them back together;
proc sort data = num_t; by 'Account number'n time; run;
proc sort data = char_t; by 'Account number'n time; run;

data have_t;
    merge char_t num_t;
    by 'Account Number'n time;
run;
* NOTE: I would leave the data in this format, and use PROCs to 
    do any further analysis;

* Tabulate to get the required results (also outputting to a data set);
proc tabulate data = have_t out=tab;
    class Result time / order = fmt;
    var Metric;
    table Result, metric * (n mean) * time / misstext="0";  
run;

* Need 2 transposes to get the correct column layout in the final data;
* First get the values from Metric_N and Metric_Mean in to 1 column;
proc transpose data = tab out = tab_t;
    by Result time;
    var metric_n metric_mean;
run;

* Then transpose them into the desired wide format;
proc transpose data = tab_t out = want (drop = _name_);
    by Result;
    id time _name_;
    var col1;
run;

* Finally re-order the columns;
data want;
    retain Result '6mMetric_N'n '7mMetric_N'n '8mMetric_N'n '9mMetric_N'n '10mMetric_N'n '11mMetric_N'n 
         '6mMetric_Mean'n '7mMetric_Mean'n '8mMetric_Mean'n '9mMetric_Mean'n '10mMetric_Mean'n '11mMetric_Mean'n; 
    set want;
run;


You can use rename in another DATA step if you need the column names to be exactly as requested.

You should really strive to work off original data in categorical form.  If your dataset is an import of some other system report (say an Excel workbook with a pivot table) you will want to reshape the data into categorical aggregates (if inputting from text @Tom has shown how in prior question).
You probably don't need a final data set that is the same 'shape' as a tabulation report, and further use if done so is just more headaches downstream and would require extraneous scaffolding (arrays/name lists/etc). If you need to 'pass along' the report as data, you might get away with using ODS EXCEL destination.
proc transpose data=have out=tposeN(rename=col1=metric) ;
  by "Account Number"n ;
run;
proc transpose data=have out=tposeC(rename=col1=group) ;
  by "Account Number"n ;
  var _character_ ;
run;
data metric(drop=_name_);
  set tposeN;
  where prxmatch('m/\d\d?m_Metric$/',trim(_name_)) ;
  period = input(substr(_name_, 1, length(_name_)-8),2.);
run ;
data group(drop=_name_);
  set tposeC;
  where prxmatch('m/\d\d?m$/',trim(_name_)) ;
  period = input(substr(_name_, 1, length(_name_)-1),2.);
run;

data reshaped ;
  merge group metric ;
  by "Account Number"n period ;
run ;

ods html file='report.html';
proc tabulate data=reshaped;
  class group period;
  var metric;
  table group,period period*metric*mean;
run;
ods html close;


